# How did they do this analysis? (weighted proportions)

Tags: descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, weighted-mean, weighted-data

I've read with interest the report by Ayanian et al "[Racial and Ethnic Disparities among Enrollees in Medicare Advantage Plans](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMsa1407273)" [1].

They have estimated **adjusted** proportions of individuals that achieved good control of blood pressure. They mention weights and reweighs and direct standardizations. Here's from the methods section:

> To estimate age-and-sex-adjusted disparities between whites and each minority group, we di- rectly standardized (reweighted) the age
>   and sex distributions of white enrollees to those of each minority
>   group in turn and compared weighted rates. We subsequently assessed
>   the contributions of regional and plan effects by reweighting the
>   distributions of white enrollees to match the dis- tributions of other
>   racial or ethnic groups accord- ing to region and then to plan.
>   Because national differences were largest between black enrollees and
>   white enrollees, we stratified these differences according to year and
>   to the four regions of the United States (Northeast, Midwest, South,
>   and West), as defined by the Census Bureau, to com- pare the magnitude
>   of adjusted differences in 2006 and 2011.

And they've obtained beautiful graphical comparisons:
[image]
!

I'm wondering how they did this technically and statistically? It's an attractive way of comparing groups and I'd like to try it out myself.

If anyone could show an example with any of the built-in data sets in R, it would be fantastic!

[1]: Ayanian, J.Z.,  Landon, B.E., Newhouse, J.P. & Zaslavsky, A. M. (2014),
"Racial and Ethnic Disparities among Enrollees in Medicare Advantage Plans,"
*N Engl J Med*; **371**:2288-2297
DOI: 10.1056/NEJMsa1407273
[link to paper](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMsa1407273)

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in what you've quoted to be completely certain. One might make quite reasonable *guesses* at exactly what they did based on that description, but it could happen that the specific details may not be identical to what they actually did in one or more ways. The way to be certain about exactly what calculations were done would be to ask the authors. If reasonable guesses are sufficient, then you'll probably get decent answers for that. Did the article come with supplementary information? Were there any other details elsewhere?

Comment: Your second image is not correctly organized, which it why it doesn't show. It would be useful to give a complete reference.

Comment: My apologies for not including the reference in the first place. It's been added now. I'm pretty fine with approximates; i.e I'm not aiming to replicate their results, I'm more interested in how they technically adjusted proportions the way they did. I'd like to do something similar. I have searched the net without any success.

Comment: You've included a link (which is good), but is not itself a reference. Links may be moved or disappear, a reference to a journal article will still be relevant in a century. I'll put one in for you.

Comment: Feel free to alter the format if you'd prefer a different one.